# how to start a counter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular to implement a counter as follows:

```
<button ng-click="order.startOperation(operation)">
   <p ng-if="counter.start"></p>
</button>
```

The button calls a function to start the counter.  I also have an `ng-if` statement so that if the counter is started, the user can see the minutes and seconds running. After the counter is started, the same button can be used to stop the counter.

```
  function startOperation(operation) {

    var operation.lastStart = Date.now();
        operation.playing = true;

  }

  // Pause an operation timer.
  function pauseOperation(operation) {
    var operation = vm.data.operations[vm.data.operations.indexOf(operation)];

    if (!operation.start) {
      operation.start = operation.lastStart;
    }

    operation.end = Date.now();

    // Sumarize the transcurred seconds.
    operation.partialTime = operation.partialTime || 0;
    operation.partialTime += Math.ceil((operation.end - operation.lastStart) / 1000);
    dataService.update();
  }
```

Comment: you want to create something like this [http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/](http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/) ?

Answer (score 0):

You need `$elapsedTime` variable that gets updated every, say, 1 second:

```
<button ng-click="order.startOperation(operation)">
    <p ng-if="counter.start">{{$elapsedTime}}</p>
</button>
```

To update its value use `$timeout` service:

```
var updateElapsedTime = function () {
    $scope.elapsedTime = Date.now() - operation.lastStart;
    if (operation.playing) {
        // keep updating
        $timeout(updateElapsedTime, 1000);
    }
}

updateElapsedTime();
```